# How to convert mboxo/mboxrd to mboxcl/mboxcl2

Tags: mutt, mbox

I am trying to export email from thunderbird so that I can read it in mutt. I have started by exporting into mbox format using the [ImportExportTools thunderbird add on](http://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html). I then copied the file to the server, but mutt told me there were no messages in the file.

After some more research it appears that [there are several variants of mbox](http://homepages.tesco.net./~J.deBoynePollard/FGA/mail-mbox-formats.html). The exported file appears to be either mboxo or mboxrd - at any rate I found a `>From` in the text of the file, and there are no Content-Length headers (as there would be in an mboxcl/mboxcl2 file).

Now according to the link above on the variants of mbox: "The mutt MUA attempts to convert "mboxo" and "mboxrd" mailboxes to "mboxcl" format." But this has obviously not happened in this case.

So does anyone know how to convert mboxo/mboxrd into mboxcl? Are there any tools available? Or am I going to have to write some code to do this ...

**Edited to add:** I exported from Thunderbird 3.0 using ImportExportTools 2.3.1.1. I have tried using mutt 1.5.20 (on Ubuntu 9.04) and 1.5.18 (on Debian Lenny).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this script. I found I needed to massage some mbox files I downloaded from Mailman-type mailing list archives to get them into a format mutt recognized. I think it's pickiest about the date format. I've not yet encountered an easier fix. But this works for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Usage:   ./mailman2mbox.py  infile outfile default-to-address
"""
import sys
from time import strftime,strptime,mktime,asctime
from email.utils import parseaddr,formatdate

if len(sys.argv) not in (3,4):
    print __doc__
    sys.exit()

out = open(sys.argv[2],"w")
listid = None
if len(sys.argv)==4:
    listid = sys.argv[3]

date_patterns = ("%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", "%d %b %H:%M:%S %Y", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", "%d %b %H:%M:%S",  "%d %b %y %H:%M:%S", "%d %b %Y %H.%M.%S",'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p')

class HeaderError(TypeError):
    pass


def finish(headers, body):
    body.append("\n")
    for n,ln in enumerate(headers):
        if ln.startswith("Date:"):
            break
    else:
        raise HeaderError("No 'Date:' header:\n" + "".join(headers)+"\n")
    if listid is not None:
        for ln2 in headers:
            if ln2.lower().startswith("list-id:"):
                break
        else:
            headers.append("List-Id: <%s>\n" % (listid,))
    date_line = ln[5:].strip()
    if date_line.endswith(')'):
        date_line = date_line[:date_line.rfind('(')].rstrip()
    if date_line[-5] in "+-":
        date_line, tz = date_line[:-5].rstrip(), int(date_line[-5:])//100
    else:
        tz = -5
    if date_line[:3] in ("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"):
        if date_line[3:5] == ', ':
            prefix = "%a, "
        elif date_line[3] == ',':
            prefix = "%a,"
        else:
            prefix = "%a "
    else:
        prefix = ""
    while True:
        for p in date_patterns:
            try:
                date_struct = strptime(date_line, prefix+p)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                break
        else:
            if not date_line:
                raise ValueError(headers[n])
            date_line = date_line[:date_line.rfind(' ')]
            continue
        break

    date_struct = list(date_struct)
    try:
        headers[n] = 'Date: %s\n' % (formatdate(mktime(date_struct),True))
        headers[0] = "%s %s\n" % (headers[0][:-25].rstrip(), asctime(date_struct), )
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError(headers[n])

    for w in headers, body:
        for s in w:
            out.write(s)


message = 0
headers, body = None, None
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    if line.startswith("From "):
        message+=1
        header = True
        if headers is not None:
            try:
                finish(headers, body)
            except HeaderError:
                message -= 1
                out.write('>')
                for w in headers, body:
                    for s in w:
                        out.write(s)
        headers, body = [], []
        line = line.replace(" at ", "@")
    elif line == '\n':
        header = False
    elif header and line.startswith('From:'):
        line = line.replace(" at ","@")
    (headers if header else body).append(line)

try:
    finish(headers, body)
except HeaderError:
    out.write('>')
    for w in headers, body:
        for s in w:
            out.write(s)

out.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I'm afraid it has not fixed my problem :(

Comment: Pity. You could try manufacturing Content-Length headers. I agree this should be more straightforward though.